# How to run GUI automation with gitlab?

Tags: python, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner, pywinauto

I have a GUI validation process that want to move from TeamCity to GitLab , unfortunately I do not know if GitLab is able to handle such a thing. I have created my `YML` file and the automation runs fine until its time  to start recognizing the GUI objects. My solution makes use of `pywinauto` which runs fine when the app shows in desktop but since GitLab do not do such a thing, I do not know if some special configuration needs to be done. `Pywinauto` error:

```
pywinauto_utilities.py, line 39, in force_WindowIdentify
active_only=active, visible_only=visible)
File “C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pywinauto-0.6.7-py2.7.egg\pywinauto\findwindows.py”, line 113, in find_window
element = find_element(**kwargs)
File “C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pywinauto-0.6.7-py2.7.egg\pywinauto\findwindows.py”, line 84, in find_element
elements = find_elements(**kwargs)
File “C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pywinauto-0.6.7-py2.7.egg\pywinauto\findwindows.py”, line 243, in find_elements
raise ctypes.WinError()
```

Comment: Not sure it would be helpful in this case, but we have [Remote Execution Guide](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/remote_execution.html). If your GitLab CI machines are local, it's a question how you're starting an agent. If it's cloud public GitLab, it's easier to use AppVeyor CI which we use for pywinauto unit tests. AppVeyor always provides active desktop.

Comment: Thanks for the pywinauto guide however this has not worked for me. I created a simple file to be triggered by windows task scheduler which runs fine as standalone but as a task just opens a few seconds and closes. Will try psexec although I do not know if its possble to use it to run it within the same machine.

Comment: Well you could have a VM, that is controlled by a standard headless runner, that has the ability to control the machines via vSphere API by code/scripts only. 

We do that for our installation tests.